# Why doesn't JavaScript's Math.cos function match this vector tutorial?

Tags: mathematics, javascript, trigonometry

I'm following [this MATHguide lesson on combining vectors](http://www.mathguide.com/lessons2/Vectors.html#combining) and have reached this part:

> Next, we need to convert their forces to horizontal and vertical components. Let's use k for Kim's vector and n for Noah's vector.
>
> k = <30, 130°> = <30 cos 130°, 30 sin 130°> = <-19.3, 23.0>.
> n = <40, 65°> = <40 cos 65°, 40 sin 65°> = <16.9, 36.3>.

To get the X part of Kim's vector, I run `30 * Math.cos(130)`, I get `-11.018739913640896`, which is not -19.3.
To get the Y part of Kim's vector, I run `30 * Math.sin(130)` which is `-27.903178505602853`, which is not the `23.0` listed by the example.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, as usual, `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` want the angle parameter in radians. You are feeding it degrees, and that's why your results are off.

You probably want to introduce an utility function `toRadians`, which takes in the angle in degrees and returns the angle in radians.

```
function toRadians(angle) {
    return (angle * Math.PI) / 180.0; 
}
```

You can find references all over the internet about angle conversions, but that's how it's done.

Now, if you execute `Math.cos(toRadians(130)) * 30`, you get about -19.3, which seems to be what you were looking for.